# React Native AlertIOS functionality to Send Message

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am using AlertIOS with my react native app:

```
AlertIOS.alert(
  'Report User',
  'Please select OK to report this user',
  [
    {text: 'Cancel', onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed'), style: 'cancel'},
    {text: 'Ok', onPress: () => console.log('Ok Pressed')},
  ],
)
```

I've got the Alert to pop-up and user can click OK, Cancel, etc.

However, i want to Send a Message to ADMIN (me) upon user click.

I would like to either send to an Email Address. OR... send to "A User on the App" (me).

How can i go about this? Can anyone provide Steps please?

Note: I do not have the app "hosted" on a server anywhere. Im only using it through Expo right now to view it in Simulator and on iPhone. Also, for DB im using Firebase.

Comment: quite vague, what sort of data storage systems are you using in your app currently?

Comment: Vague? I wish to send a msg from "Report User" button. Regarding your question, as mentioned in my post, I am only using Firebase for DB.